# How to Multithread with web scraping in python?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

I am sorry I don't know very well multithreads. SO my question could appear a little dummy.
I have a page that I would like to scrape with multithreading to accelerate the process.
I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

codes = [1829, 1321, 6536, 6426, 558, 380, 1850, 4923, 5961, 4925]
# a sub part of codes because it is not possible to print all here

def AuM_sdg(code_sdg):
    try:
        code_sdg = str(code_sdg)
        url = "https://www.quantalys.com/espace/" + code_sdg
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
        data = soup.select_one("#chartEncours8a input")["value"]
        data = json.loads(data)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data['dataProvider'])
        df['unit'] = data['valueAxes'][0]['unit']
        return df
    except:
        pass
   
pool = ThreadPool(8)
results = process_map(AuM_sdg, codes)
```

but I get an error message:
`BrokenProcessPool: A child process terminated abruptly, the process pool is not usable anymore`

Moreover what does  the 8 in ThreadPool(8) means ? What number should I put ?

I tried to web scrape with multithread

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put there concrete URL and what you're trying to get from that page.

Comment: The `(8)` tells it to run no more than 8 threads at a time.

Comment: Does your code work if you run those sequentially (like, say, `results = [AuM_sdg(c) for c in codes]`?

Comment: @TimRoberts how do I know what number to input ?

Comment: @TimRoberts this code works: ```
df_aum = pd.DataFrame()
for code in tqdm(codes):
    try:
        df_aum = pd.concat([df_aum, 
                            AuM_sdg(code).drop('unit', axis=1)
                            ],
                           axis=1
                           )
    except:
        pass```

Comment: 8 is just fine.  If you leave that off, it uses 5 times the number of processors you have.  Why do you need the `except: pass`?

Comment: @timroberts in case there is no data to web scrape. In that case I need to pass

Comment: Then CHECK for that.  I believe your blanket `except` is hiding the problem.  Your code runs perfectly fine for me if I remove the `try` and `except`.  I had to import `json`, `requests`, and `BeautifulSoup`.